# Adding label to core plot chart

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to add a label to a core plot scatter chart. It should be at a specific y value at the left edge of the chart, like that:

[image: a graph with a label]

I tried doing it using annotation but I have a problem with dragging. When I drag the chart the annotation is also being dragged, and I would like it to always stay at the left edge.

Comment: What kind of annotation did you use? A layer annotation is anchored to a fixed spot within the host layer. It only moves when the whole layer moves or resizes.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your response
I did use layer (CPTextLayer to be precise)

The label should get its Y position from the graph data (as shown value of 8.7 in approximate)
and should get its X position from the physical graph location (as shown, the left of the graph) and has no connection to specific x value
When the graph moves the label should remain in the left of the graph but to move up/down if necessary and remain above the same Y point (8.7 in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your label as a plot space annotation. Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the `xRange` and update the x-value of the anchor point as needed. You can use the plot space to convert the desired x-position to the corresponding data value for the anchor point.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
What I was missing is the method of when to update the annotation location. I ended up assigning to the notification CPGraphNeedsRedrawNotification and there i updated the location.